# How can I check if a Ringtone exists?

Tags: android, backup, ringtone

In my app, I'm storing the user's choice of a ringtone in a SharedPreference file. When the app is reinstalled and the [backup is restored](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html), I want to check if the ringtone still exists on the device, because if it doesn't I would want to use the default ringtone (as opposed to playing nothing).

So to do so, I plan on overriding the `onRestore` method and checking if the ringtone is available on the device.

So how can I go about checking if a ringtone exists on the Android device (I would prefer the most lightweight method possible)?

Comment: depends on what you are storing about the ringtone in your file. But I think your two options are either get a File object reference and check .exists() OR query the Media ContentProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are storing the ringtone as a `content://` `Uri` value, I would use either `openInputStream()` or `getType()` on `ContentResolver`. `getType()` is probably "the most lightweight", but it might be prone to false negatives (e.g., ringtone exists but the MIME type cannot be determined for some reason).